# InsertAll failing with templateSuffix

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to streaming data to tables in BigQuery using templateSuffix.

The payload:

```
{
    'rows': [{
        'insertId': u '47669460689243',
        'ignoreUnknownValues': True,
        'json': {
            'city': u 'jarinu',
            'cookies': [],
            'remote_addr': u '1.1.1.1',
            'country': u 'BR',
            'region': u 'sp',
            'publishTime': u '2016-10-29T00:04:03.280Z',
            'publishTimeUTC': u '2016-10-29T00:04:03.280Z',
            'cityLatLong': u '-23.103663,-46.728509',
            'user_agent': u 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36',
            'messageId': u '47669460689243',
            'path': u '/hit/ga',
            'arguments': []
        },
        'templateSuffix': '20161029'
    }]
}
```

When I submit this streaming job, I see a errorless response:

```
{"kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse"}
```

But the table will never be created :(

The schema I've used to create the template original table:

```
{
  'fields': [{
    'name': 'messageId',
    'type': 'STRING',
    'mode': 'REQUIRED'
  }, {
    'name': 'publishTimeUTC',
    'type': 'TIMESTAMP',
    'mode': 'REQUIRED'
  }, {
    'name': 'publishTime',
    'type': 'STRING',
    'mode': 'REQUIRED'
  }, {
    'name': 'remote_addr',
    'type': 'STRING',
    'mode': 'REQUIRED'
  }, {
    'name': 'user_agent',
    'type': 'STRING',
    'mode': 'REQUIRED'
  }, {
    'name': 'cookies',
    'type': 'RECORD',
    'mode': 'REPEATED',
    'fields': [{
      'name': 'name',
      'type': 'STRING',
      'mode': 'REQUIRED'
    }, {
      'name': 'value',
      'type': 'STRING',
      'mode': 'NULLABLE'
    }, ]
  }, {
    'name': 'country',
    'type': 'STRING',
    'mode': 'NULLABLE'
  }, {
    'name': 'region',
    'type': 'STRING',
    'mode': 'NULLABLE'
  }, {
    'name': 'city',
    'type': 'STRING',
    'mode': 'NULLABLE'
  }, {
    'name': 'cityLatLong',
    'type': 'STRING',
    'mode': 'NULLABLE'
  }, {
    'name': 'path',
    'type': 'STRING',
    'mode': 'REQUIRED'
  }, {
    'name': 'arguments',
    'type': 'RECORD',
    'mode': 'REPEATED',
    'fields': [{
      'name': 'name',
      'type': 'STRING',
      'mode': 'REQUIRED'
    }, {
      'name': 'value',
      'type': 'STRING',
      'mode': 'REPEATED'
    }, ]
  }, ]
}
```

But when I run this code without the template suffix, feeding a "traditional" table, It happens ok immediately!

Are the any problems with my schema, my payload? Am I'm missing something?

Comment: I work on bigquery. Can you please let me know the project, dataset, table name, and the time when you invoked the API? Then we can have a look.

Comment: Hi! It would be great!
project: dp6-stargate, dataset: ga, table: hit_ times: 2016-10-28 between 22h and 23h

Comment: My co-worker chased some information in the background for you case, and it seems like the streaming system get something on 10/28 and handle it over without error. However he could not find the detail logs for your cases as the log is expired for the normal case. Could you resend your streaming request so we could get a full details to you? Also attach the project/dataset/table name here after you retry it.

Comment: Sure!

I've re-sent right now!
project: dp6-stargate, dataset: leo, table: hit_ 
The job includes 'templateSuffix': '20161029' but the data goes directly to the template table (hit_)

Comment: Please look at BiGang's reply below and see if that works (he is my co-worker but cannot add comment yet) .

Comment: I've tried again, same job data, can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

What does your request look like? The template_suffix should be part of the insert request instead of row, check here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#template-tables

To use a template table via the BigQuery API, add a templateSuffix parameter to your insertAll request.

Comment: I've tried to add templateSuffix as a key in BQ Job request, but it doesn't works also, the job returns ok but it simply doesn't happens...

Comment: No problems, but, suddenly, everything is working :O
The Job data: 
{'rows': [{'json': {'messageId': u'123.1478709266.81', 'country': u'BR', 'city': u'jarinu', 'publishTime': '2016-11-09T16:34:26.810887Z', 'publishTimeUTC': '2016-11-09T16:34:26.810887Z', 'path': u'/hit/test', 'cityLatLong': u'-23.103663,-46.728509', 'region': u'sp', 'remote_addr': u'1.1.1.1', 'user_agent': u'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'}, 'insertId': u'123.1478709266.81'}], 'templateSuffix': '20161109'}

Comment: Just one question: If I push thousands of stream inserts to buffer using TemplateSuffix, can I expect that every insert will be succeed correctly in the right table in case of a fresh new table needs to be created? 

(In my previous strategy I was pre-creating tables 1 day before to ensure that after 23:59 every insert will work, but I'm wondering If I move to templateSuffix I'll do get new tables created instantly and every new buffered inserts ill work also)

Comment: Yes, every one will be created successfully and independently. The streaming system will handle the new table creation. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the "missing" table is probably because you previously deleted a table with the same name.

If I create a table called `foobar`, then deleted, another table created called `foobar` doesn't seem to show up. I seem to remember this is documented somewhere but can't find it right now.

Comment: It makes sense! 
I've found another related issue here https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/issues/53